# How to validate datetime object in SPARQL? (Virtuoso 22007 Error DT006)

Tags: rdf, sparql, freebase, dbpedia, virtuoso

I get the following error.

```
Virtuoso 22007 Error DT006: Cannot convert -0359 to datetime : Incorrect month field length

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 select ?item  bif:year(xsd:dateTime( str(?dob))) as ?m{
?item <h://f.cm/ns/common/topic/notable_types> <h://f.cm/ns/people/person> .
?item <h://f.cm/ns/people/person/date_of_birth> ?dob 
} limit 675
```

If I change the limit to `674`, it works.

What I suspected was that some datetime field is wrong somewhere and printed `?dob`, which revealed that one of the values is `-0359`.

Solution is to validate the value before applying `bif` function.

But, how can we validate datetime in SPARQL?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I found this question via Google because I had the same problem. Looking elsewhere for help, I found the following solution:

```
SELECT * {

  ?s ?p ?o

  FILTER ( datatype(?o) = xsd:datetime )
  FILTER ( coalesce(xsd:datetime(str(?o)), '!') != '!')

}
```

This worked for me.

Note that I found the answer to this at [SemanticWeb](https://web.archive.org/web/20150111120450/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/20825/how-to-get-data-that-dont-match-their-datatype-in-sparql#20828).

Comment: No luck with same approach here. Also no luck with: FILTER (regex(str(?o), '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]')) FILTER (xsd:datetime(?o) > '" + minBirthDate + "'^^xsd:datetime). What is coalesce(...) here?

Comment: Coalesce in the above query does what the name suggests: it concatenates the result of the conversion of ?o to a datetime with an exclamation mark. If the result of that is just an exclamation mark, then that means that the datetime is empty and hence, ?o was not a valid datetime. Since we filter on results that do NOT coalesce to just '!', we filter on values that are indeed a valid datetime. Does that make it more clear to you?

Comment: @TextGeek ... a bit late, but does your minBirthDate really have xsd:datetime or just xsd:date (like mine) :) `FILTER ( datatype(?sdate) = xsd:date )
  FILTER ( coalesce(xsd:date(str(?sdate)), '!') = '!')`

Comment: @Richard Sorry, I don't recall after this long; I probably just copied and pasted it from my code, so it would be as shown... :(