# How to validate whether a string is a dateTime object or not?

Tags: rdf, sparql, freebase, dbpedia, virtuoso

I get some invalid dateString from freebase data.
Output of the following sparql query is

Query:

```
select ?dob dataType(?dob) as ?dataType {
<http://freebase.com/ns/m/011k9p> <h://freebase.com/ns/common/topic/notable_types> <http://freebase.com/ns/people/person> .
<http://freebase.com/ns/m/011k9p> <h://freebase.com/ns/people/person/date_of_birth> ?dob 
}
```

Output:

```
dob     dataType
-0359   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
```

dob getting -0359 is making age computation on this field impossible (since i cannot convert it to xsd:dateTime object).

How to check whether a string can be casted to a type?

Thanks in Advance.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896118/virtuoso-22007-error-dt006-how-to-validate-datetime-object-in-sparql

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing is to just use SimpleDateFormat to try and parse the string:

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(theDate);
```

If you catch a ParseException, you know its not formatted as a valid date time string and you can then proceed however you wish, throw an error, print a warning, try to fix it into a valid date time, etc.